# How to make swagger endpoint available only for testing environment?

Tags: java, api, swagger

In automation tests, I have a problem with connecting to the database of the testing environment in order to clear the database before and after tests.

But there is a script in the backend repo that clears the database and which I could use.
I thought that the easiest way to trigger this script would be by calling a swagger API endpoint provided by the backend.

But in order to keep the production environment safe, this endpoint should be available only in the testing environment.

But how to do this properly?

Comment: You can use hidden = true into annotation @ApiOperation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `@Profile({"!prod && swagger"})` on configuration class.

```
@Configuration 
@Profile({"!prod && swagger"})
public class SwaggerConfig {
    ..
}
```

Comment: why curly brackets?